# Team Foundation Server Error - TFS206018 -add solution to source control

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi I have problem add solution to TFS 2010.  First I describe to you scenario.

I installed TFS 2010 on Server 2008 - machine : Zeus.

Then I created Team Project collection with  TFS Admin console.

Name of Team Project collection is Pokec.sk.

I am trying add VS solution from another machine : Ares.

On machine Ares I have VS 2010.

First I configure connection to TFS 2010. On connection from VS to TFS I used credential from machine Zeus.

I used this credentials: zeus\administrator. Because I cant use credential from machine Ares.

When I tried add solution to source control I got this error:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/cnik5

I think that I am trying add solution to TFS under credentials ares\tom and this is not allowed.

I tried edit Group Membership with TFS Admin console. But I dont know how can I add credentials from another location.

I think it is security problem of TFS. Because Ares\tom is not in Group Membership of Pokec.sk.

```
Machine: Zeus  User: Zeus\Administrator  SW: TFS 2010

Machine: Ares  User:Ares\tom             SW: VS 2010
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can only add users to TFS that are either users on the current workstation, or users in a domain that you are joined to (or that is in a trust relationship with the domain you are joined to.)  You can't simply add users on ARES, instead you have to add a user on ZEUS and then you can authenticate as that user from ARES.

You need to create a new user on ZEUS (for example, `ZEUS\tom`), and then grant that user access to TFS.  From ARES, you will then connect to ZEUS as `ZEUS\tom`, and you will be prompted for a password each time you connect.

If your goal is to avoid typing a password each time you connect, then you have two choices:

1. You can configure these credentials in Control Panel -> Credential Manager so that any time you connect to ZEUS, it will provide the credentials for `ZEUS\tom`.
2. You can take advantage of Windows "shadow accounts".  Simply use the same username and password for the user on ZEUS as exists for a user on ARES.  Then the credentials presented by ARES will match the corresponding user on ZEUS and you will be logged in automatically.