# I want to configure TFS2015 and have VS2019 show following error

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

In solution explorer new Team option is also not visible

TF206018: The items could not be added to source control because either no team projects have been set up, or because you do not have permission to access any of the team projects in the current collection.

Comment: Please add documentation links for the process you are following to do the configuration. Also tag this for VS2019.
Try to look for help on this site (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521301/team-foundation-server-error-tfs206018-add-solution-to-source-control)
and online (https://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/tfs/TF206018_items_could_not_be_added.htm)

Comment: @for lrbt Do you still have this issue now? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT...I use VS2015 to continue my work. Didn't find any reliable ans to "add team project" in VS2019. VS2019 Support DevOps server only.

Comment: @for lrbt For those older versions of TFS such as TFS 2015, you can see on the [support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops) they are listed as “High level of support”. Unfortunately Create Team Project was one of the features that is no longer supported from the client. See explanation from the product group(Ed Glas [MSFT]
) in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/690875/cannot-create-a-new-team-project-from-within-the-t.html).

Comment: @for lrbt  Hi friend, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Please find more detailed information in this ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/690875/cannot-create-a-new-team-project-from-within-the-t.html.

According to the workaround from the product group, please use the "New Project" button on the home page of the org / collection in the web experience.

If you are using an older version of TFS that does not have this option available in the web, you will need to install an older version of Visual Studio that has that option available.

Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017 is a great option. It is free, installs side by side with VS 2019, has minimal footprint, and installs in less than 5 minutes. Download page is [here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017).

Please vote and add your comments in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/690875/cannot-create-a-new-team-project-from-within-the-t.html) if you have any questions.